# How to export an IPython notebook to HTML for a blog post?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

What is the best way to get an ipython notebook into html format for use in a blog post?

It is easy to turn an ipython notebook into a PDF, but I'd rather publish as an html notebook.

I've found that if I download the notebook as a .ipynb file, then load it onto gist, then look at it with the ipython notebook viewer (nbviewer.ipython.org), THEN grab the html source, I can paste it into a blog post (or just load it as html anywhere) and it looks about right.  However, if I use the "print view" option directly from ipython, the source contains a bunch of javascript rather than the processed html, which is not useful since the images and text are not directly included.

The `%pastebin` magic is also not particularly helpful for this task, since it pastes the python code and not the ipython notebook formatted code.

EDIT: Note that this is under development; see the comments under the accepted answer.

EDIT May 2 2014: As per Nathaniel's comment, a new answer is needed for ipython 2.0

Comment: Change made.  There is probably an answer hidden in Damian Avila's blog: http://www.damian.oquanta.info/posts/deploy-your-nikola-powered-blog-content-from-the-ipython-notebook.html

Answer (score 17):

The right way is described in: http://blog.fperez.org/2012/09/blogging-with-ipython-notebook.html. Then you can do `nbconvert -f blogger-html your_notebook.ipynb` to get the html code for your post.

Comment: nbconvert got moved to the IPython repo https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/IPython/nbconvert

Comment: And now it's part of the official ipython 1.0 release.

Comment: The correct usage is `ipython nbconvert --to html IPyNotebookTestBlogPost.ipynb` in the dev version (v2.0)

Comment: This answer is sadly out of date. As far as I can tell, there is no longer any option corresponding to the `-f blogger-html` used in that post. The `--to html` option spits out everything including all the load/save buttons at the top of the page, and it does't appear to generate header code to put in the blogger template. If there's a way to get it to work with blogger it's not documented, and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 11):

One step further from the answer above. To create a PDF file,

1. create a tex file

   ```
   nbconvert -f latex your_notebook.ipynb
   ```
2. convert tex to pdf :

   ```
   pdflatex your_notebook.tex
   ```

Comment: Is there any benefit to this approach over simply "printing" and saving as PDF?  i.e., does texing improve formatting at all?

Comment: Try it! It does change quite a bit.

Answer (score 8):

All the above answers seems outdated. Here is the most modern solution taken from the official `nbconvert`[docs](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

`$ jupyter nbconvert --to FORMAT notebook.ipynb`

The default output format is `html`, for which the `--to` argument may be omitted:

`$ jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb`

Comment: Could you add some information about how to change style etc?  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Click on file > Download > html

Answer (score 1):

You generate the html from cmd, with your Jupyter Notebook open:

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/47773252/15117772 answered a similar question:

Also pass the --execute flag to generate the output cells

`jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html notebook.ipynb`

`jupyter nbconvert --execute --to pdf notebook.ipynb`

Comment: This is the latest and most up to date answer. Thanks.