# How to export current notebook in HTML on Jupyter

Tags: python, html, jupyter

How can I export the current notebook (from inside the notebook itself, using **Python**) to HTML (to a custom output path)?

Answer (score 39):

By looking at [nbconvert docs](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), you'll see that you can use [--to html](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-html) method:

```
import os

os.system('jupyter nbconvert --to html yourNotebook.ipynb')
```

This will create a `yourNotebook.html` file inside `yourNotebook.ipynb` folder.

Answer (score 18):

You can do it. Use the following very simple steps:

I am using:
OS: Ubuntu, Anaconda-Jupyter notebook, Python 3

## 1 Save your Notebook in HTML format:

1. Start the jupyter notebook that you want to save in HTML format. First save the notebook properly so that HTML file will have a latest saved version of your code/notebook.
2. Run the following command from the notebook itself:

   `!jupyter nbconvert --to html your_notebook_name.ipynb`

Edit: or you can also use:
`!jupyter nbconvert  your_notebook_name.ipynb --to html`

After execution will create HTML version of your notebook and will save it in the current working directory. You will see one html file will be added into the current directory with `your_notebook_name.html` name

(`your_notebook_name.ipynb` --> `your_notebook_name.html`).

If you want to know how to save it into pdf format please check my answer on this question as well: [IPython notebook - unable to export to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755574/ipython-notebook-unable-to-export-to-pdf/54918257#54918257)

Comment: Hi Yogesh, the disclaimer "please upvote" you're adding to all your answers is against the rules.

Comment: Sorry I will remove the line.

Comment: It does convert the .ipynb to .html. However, it doesn't generate with outputs of cell

Answer (score 6):

Actually you need to save your notebook first, then you can use the nbconvert command

It would be something like:

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.save_notebook()
```

And Then

```
import os
os.system('jupyter nbconvert --to html yourNotebook.ipynb')
```

If you do not do this, it will not convert the actual notebook.

Comment: Can you also make the yourNotebook.ipynb flexible?

Answer (score 4):

The above answer yields the result .ipynb to .html. But it exports .html file without output. In addition, if you want .html file with output, please use also `--execute`.

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html notebook.ipynb
```

Comment: Hello, any idea how to add --allow_errors=True to this?