# Merging an HTML document while still preserving LaTex rendering

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have several sheets in Jupyter Lab that I want to export and combine into a single HTML file. I still want it to be formatted just as if I exported a single sheet to HTML. How do I do this? I need to be able to share my code to people who don't have Jupyter Lab, and PDF won't work because there is no way to copy the flattened text.

Comment: You can read it [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896866/how-to-export-current-notebook-in-html-on-jupyter)

Comment: if you know how to export single sheet to HTML then you could crop `HMTL` (because it is normal `string`) and concatenate it. You could remove all before `<body>` and after `</body>` and join together, and later add again all before `<body>` and after `</body>`