# How to use nbconvert from Jupyter Notebook to HTML

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get a practical example to use nbconvert.
I have seen a lot of blogs but I can get the idea right.
How do I select the folder where the Jupyter notebook is located and the destination folder for the HTML output? what is the right syntaxis to do it using Windows?
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is outdated, so I'm sharing the updated version:

Run this in the terminal:

```bash
pip install nbconvert
jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to html
```

`nbconvert` is very flexible, for example, you can convert to pdf:

```bash
jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to pdf
```

And there are flavors to each format. For example, to get a barebones HTML (no CSS):

```bash
jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to html --template basic
```

Answer (score 2):

If you not afraid of command line then it must be as simple and comprehensive as this example:

`ipython nbconvert --to html "C:\path\to\your_notebook.ipynb"`

It will generate a HTML file named `your_notebook.html` at same place where `your_notebook.ipynb` is located.

If you need to take control over target HTML file generation you can ask `ipython` to output into standard output and redirect its output to whatever file you want.

Example:

`ipython nbconvert --to html "C:\path\to\your_notebook.ipynb" --stdout > "C:\my\reports\fancy_analytic.html"`

This will render `your_notebook.ipynb` in HTML format into `fancy_analytics.html` file.

[More info here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html)