# How export a Jupyter notebook to HTML from the command line?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visualization, jupyter

I'm writing test visualization program based on test results. 
I want to run jupyter notebook via terminal and generate html page to show it to user without showing the editable scripts to user.
Can I do that? Or suggest the better way to show visualized test results.

Comment: [nbconvert](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can execute a notebook and convert it to HTML (or other formats). To hide code, you'll need a [custom template](https://github.com/jupyter/ngcm-tutorial/blob/master/Day-2/nbconvert_templates/foldcode.tpl).

Answer (score 53):

**Also use `--execute` to get the output**

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html notebook.ipynb
```

This produces a `notebook.html` file.

The best practice is to keep the output out of the notebook for version control, see: [Using IPython notebooks under version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734739/using-ipython-notebooks-under-version-control)

But then, if you don't pass `--execute`, the output won't be present in the HTML, see also: [How to run an .ipynb Jupyter Notebook from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/running-ipynb-from-terminal)

For an HTML fragment without header: [How to export an IPython notebook to HTML for a blog post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502187/ipython-notebook-to-html-for-blog-post)

Tested in Jupyter 4.4.0.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can and it's quite easy and a built in feature

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb
```

That will generate a *notebook.html* file. Output [can be customized](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html). Also check out the slideshow functionality (View>Cell-Toolbar>Slideshow) which can also be used with nbconvert.

Also the *notebook.ipynb* Jupyter file can be uploaded to Github where the current version gets rendered. Depending on what you want that information might be useful too

Also check out line/cell magic. You can run bash commands directly in your jupyter cell like so:

```
%%bash
convert graphviz/MyPic.jpg -resize 70% graphviz/MyPic_sm.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

I developed jupyter-runner (https://github.com/omar-masmoudi/jupyter-runner) which is a simple wrapper around "jupyter nbconvert".

Several notebooks can be executed, with parameters, with parallel workers, input/output located in S3 and mail sending capabilities.