# how to correctly export a jupyter notebook with data to html

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook

I have anaconda/jupyter installed on linux.
also using appmode to publish to webapp
is there a way to correctly save this to html
if I use nbconvert in command line : the output from %sql commands is not included - only plots
when I displayed the notebook with appmode and selected save as html (browser option) the markdown code is included, but the data from sql commands is squeezed… and not usable
is there a way to correctly save this and use this for a presentation ?
thanks for all answers
best regards, Guy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How export a Jupyter notebook to HTML from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901154/how-export-a-jupyter-notebook-to-html-from-the-command-line)

Comment: yes, but as indicated in my post the output from %sql is not included in this file - only the plots are present

Comment: To be clear, you've used the `--execute` flag as per the selected answer in the linked question?

Comment: thks for the update : I have used the execute flag  ubuntu@ubuntu:/data/jupyter$ /Software/Anaconda/bin/jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html DB2_HEALTCHECK.ipynb
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook DB2_HEALTCHECK.ipynb to html
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3
[NbConvertApp] Writing 467844 bytes to DB2_HEALTCHECK.html
 but only the cells tagged as initialyse are executed (upto the connect to db)   the cell that are not tagged tp initialize are not executed - can we also specify -- execute all or similar       best regards, Guy