# Python Interactive Jupyter notebooks (".py") to HTML straight conversion

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, export, python-interactive

Is there any way to directly convert the ".py" files with cells as outlined here (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) to HTML?

Currently, I can first convert the ".py" to a normal ".ipynb", then from there I can export it to anything, but I am looking for a one step solution, just for simplicity.

Searched online help etc, could not find a solution.

Comment: Use an `jupyter nbconvert` command to point at the `.ipynb` file and specify the output type, you'll want `--to html`, see [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-as-a-command-line-tool). Something like `jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb` run where you normally trigger Jupyter launch from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How export a Jupyter notebook to HTML from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901154/how-export-a-jupyter-notebook-to-html-from-the-command-line)